# Qual é o nome dos conjunto de caracteres numéricos?

Tags: origem, números, nomes

O nosso alfabeto é baseado no alfabeto latino e hoje é denominado com o mesmo nome (latino ou romano). O sistema numérico é arábico mas os símbolos (caracteres) possuem o mesmo nome ?

Qual é o nome deste conjunto de caracteres/símbolos (algarismos)? Qual a sua origem? **1234567890**

Comment: Queres saber a origem dos próprios números (caracteres escritos), ou da palavra que usamos para descrevê-los (*números*, *cifras*)?

Comment: numeração indo-arábica, no seu caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com [a Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algarismos_indo-ar%C3%A1bicos), o conjunto dos algarismos é mesmo denominado de algarismos arábicos ou indo-arábicos (ênfase meu):

> **Algarismos arábicos ou indo-arábicos são os dez dígitos: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 e 9**, criados com base no sistema numérico Indo-arábico, o sistema mais comum para a representação simbólica de números no mundo atual.

[A página da Wikipedia sobre o sistema numérico indo-arábico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_num%C3%A9rico_hindu-ar%C3%A1bico) também parece ir ao encontro desta (ênfase meu, outra vez):

> O sistema numérico hindu-arábico* é um sistema em uma base de dez, usando um símbolo para zero. É atualmente o mais usado no mundo. **Seus símbolos são também chamados de algarismos indo-arábicos.**